# writing registry values in ROISCAN script

Tags: vbscript

I am using following VBScript in ROISCAN script to write registry values, but it is not working, if I execute the script independently it is working fine. not sure why, appreciate your help.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyKey\MySubKey\MSOfficeBit"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey,12,"REG_SZ"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

ROISCAN Script URL:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/68b80aba-130d-4ad4-aa45-832b1ee49602

Comment: Although I know nothing about this subject, can you show us what it is that's not working? Do you get an error? Or no result at all? etc.

Comment: no error, just no result at all..

Answer (score 0):

it has to be a permissions issue in ROISCAN.  www.microsoft.com/sysinternals   there is a program called filemon(and you can filter for just one executable so you don't see everything executing on your computer, which will show you RIOSCAN running and what user and if it found the file, and if there was file permission errors

Comment: running with user Admin

Comment: when you run it the script independently does windows ask for escalation?  even as admin, admin can be asked for escalation.  this can be turned off fyi

Comment: independently means if I put the above script in separate file and run, it works fine. it doesn't work if I put in ROISCAN script and run it.

Comment: when you run that file, does windows prompt you for anything when you run it?

Comment: no, it does not prompt any thing, however if I run ROISCAN script, status comes in command prompt what is happening in the script, and goes away after complete execution.

Comment: `Filemon` has been retired (as has `Regmon`). Their functionality has been incorporated in [`Process Monitor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). I have a [mini HOWTO](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/submission.shtml) on tracking permissions issues with these tools on my homepage.